# Proving that something is a cycle

Tags: group-theory

Let $a_1,...,a_k,b$ be distinct integers in ${1,.....n}$ and let and $l$ be in index in the range $1\leq l \leq k$. Prove that $(a_lb)(a_1a_2....a_k)(a_lb)$ is a cycle.

Maybe my question in general, is how do you prove anything is a cycle, or how does one even start going about this?

Comment: Maybe you mean "Prove that $(a_lb)(a_1...a_k)(a_lb)$ *is a cycle*." [italics only for emphasis.]

Comment: You are all correct, I definitely missed that last word, trying to prove it is a cycle.

Comment: You just need to find explicitly the product of disjoint cycles form for the product you refer to. For that one needs to know whether you compute products left-to-right or right-to-left, and some notation about where $b$ "fits" among the various $a_j$.

Comment: **Hint:** $$(a_lb)^{-1}=(a_lb).$$

Comment: Your permutation is a conjugated one of a $k$-cycle, so it's again a $k$-cycle: conjugation in $S_n$ preserves the cycle structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that $(a_lb)(a_1\dots a_k)(a_lb)=(a_1\dots a_{l-1}ba_{l+1}\dots a_k)$.

This is a special case of $π^{-1}(x_1\dots x_k)π=(π(x_1)\dotsπ(x_k))$, for permutations $π$.